# I want my HTML code to run in Edge, not Chrome, how can I do that?

Tags: html

I would like my code HTML code to run on Edge because I'm more familiar with it, how can I do that?

Comment: Not relevant but anyway you can [set Edge as your default browser](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-default-browser-in-windows-10-020c58c6-7d77-797a-b74e-8f07946c5db6)

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to directly run code in Edge. But there is two options to do this.
Option 1: You can open it using -> Open With -> EDGE Select.
Option 2: You can set the EDGE as a default browser. Then you just click and open.

Answer (score -1):

one way to do is -> Save it to text file in html format (.html extension) and drag drop it to edge browser.

if you scenario is more complex then update your question.